# Function return Char array C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I try to return char array from function. I am new in C and try to learn function return value.
This is my code:

```
int main()
{
unsigned int nr;
unsigned int mask=32;

char *outString;

printf("Enter Nr:\n");
scanf("%u",&nr);

outString = getBinary(nr,mask);
printf("%s",outString);
//getch();
return 0;
}

char * getBinary(int nr,int mask)
{
static char outPut[sizeof(mask)]="";
 while(mask>0)
{
 if((nr&mask)==0)
    {
        strcat(outPut,"0");
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(outPut,"1");
    }
    mask=mask>>1;
  }

//printf("%s",outPut);
return outPut;
}
```

I can't make program work! With two error on function call.

Comment: what error you get??

Comment: Implicit declaration of function. And assignment make pointer rom integer with out a casting.

Comment: Try to put a prototype `char * getBinary(int nr,int mask);` before your `main`

Comment: thank, works perfect.

Comment: @AliAbdulhussein: Well, it probably works as long as you put no more than 3 digits in the `outPut` array (assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your machine. You should make it larger. Also, you will see a problem if you call `getBinary` more than once, because the new number's digits will be appended to the old number's digits. You should set `output[0] = '\0';` before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem is, `sizeof(mask)` is not doing what you think it does. This is equivalent to `sizeof(int)` which is not what you want there.

You should better stick to a pointer and memory allocator function for this purpose.

FYI, you don't see issues currently with

```
 static char outPut[sizeof(mask)] "";
```

as `sizeof` is a compile time operator, so this `outPut` is not VLA. As soon as you *try to* change it to

```
static char outPut[mask] = "";
```

you'll face problems, as

- VLAs are local scope and incomplete type, `static` storage is not allowed.
- you cannot initialize VLAs.

Also, you must provide the prototype (forward declaration) to `getBinary()` if you intend to define it after `main()`.

Comment: Returning a local variable(array) `outPut` leads to UB even if it is static?

Comment: His problem is he doesn't have a prototype for the function `getBinary()`

Comment: @Gopi there's a bigger one, hidden,

Comment: @Gopi also, what makes you think that `sizeof(mask)` is not an issue?

Comment: When did I say it is not an issue?

Comment: @Gopi ok, then I might have misunderstood the [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586337/function-return-char-array-c/40586375#comment68408156_40586375), sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can change program like following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char * getBinary(int nr,int mask); // add function header, it necessary to avoid compilation error 
//otherwise you can move getBinary function before your main function, because the compilator cannot recognize your function when it is defined after the call.
int main()
{
unsigned int nr;
unsigned int mask=32;

char *outString;

printf("Enter Nr:\n");
scanf("%u",&nr);

outString = getBinary(nr,mask);
printf("%s",outString);
//getch();
return 0;
}

char * getBinary(int nr,int mask)
{
static char outPut[sizeof(mask)]="";
 while(mask>0)
{
 if((nr&mask)==0)
    {
        strcat(outPut,"0");
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(outPut,"1");
    }
    mask=mask>>1;
  }

//printf("%s",outPut);
return outPut;
}
```